# multiply all lists in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of masks and I want to obtain the resulting mask by multiplying all of them.
My Donkey Kong approach is the following:

```
a = [[1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
b = a[0]
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    b = b * np.array(a[i])
```

which I think it works as returns `[1,0]` as value of `b`.

Is there a nicer way of doing this?

---

EDIT: I am looking for common ranges in the mask.
To find all the non zero ranges I do the following:
label = 0

```
for i in range(1, len(labels)):
   label = label + np.array(labels[i])
label = [1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in label]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [np.prod](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html), which returns the product of array elements over a given axis:

```py
import numpy as np
a = [[1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
np.prod(a, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I see that you are already using numpy so it can be used like other answers suggested. But still, a nice built-in solution only using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) can be:

```py
from functools import reduce

a = [[1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]]

def element_wise_multiply(list1, list2):
    return [x*y for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]

b = reduce(element_wise_multiply, a)

# Or as a lambda:
b = reduce(lambda list1, list2: [x*y for x,y in zip(list1, list2)], a)
```

This takes every two sub-lists and *reduces* them to one by multiplying all index-matching elements by using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). It also gives:

```
[1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.prod`:

```
>>> np.prod(a, axis=0)
array([1, 0])
>>>
```

Or you could use `np.cumprod` and get the last value:

```
>>> np.cumprod(a, axis=1)[-1]
array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
>>> np.array(a).prod(axis=0)
array([1, 0])
```

which multiplies elements within eeach column.

or with `all` to get a boolean result

```
>>> np.array(a).all(axis=0)
array([ True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

A built-in way with `all` that short circuits (no other answer short circuits now):

```
>>> [all(column) for column in zip(*a)]
[True, False]
```

where `zip(*a)` kindof transposes to produce "columns" as sublists here and we check if all entries are truthful. `all` has a short circuting behaviour.

You can `int(all(sub))` to cast results to integer after `all`'in the sublists.